# Should I be using a Dictionary or List with a linq search?

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I am using C# to create a grid that is made up of cells. The cells will use 'sbyte X' and 'sbyte Y' to determine location in the grid (0,0 is top-left).  The Cell is a class and will store it's own location in the grid.

I am wondering if it would be better to use:

```
List<Cell> CellList
//....
Cell thisCell = CellList.First(cell => cell.X = thisX && cell.Y = thisY);
```

or to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<sbyte[], Cell> CellList
//....
Cell thisCell = CellList[new sbyte[2] { thisX , thisY }];
```

Also, a collection of cells will usually be between 25 and 50 in each direction; so 625 - 2500 entries. I am interested in know about both speed and memory issues. There will probably be a total of 7 grids loaded up at the same time and several cells from each grid will be processed each cycle.

Comment: Depending on your needs (could the sizes change once the "grid" has been initialized?) you might want to use an efficient 2-dimensions array

Comment: I would do a `Cell[,]`, letting the array coordinates be the cell coordinates.

Comment: once the grid has been created the size will stay the same (all grids will be the same size) and the object associated with each cell wont change.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers. Wondering how the `Cell[,]` compares to the `Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>, Cell>` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is not going to work, because arrays do not override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in a way that would use the data stored in the array. The first approach, however, would be slow for collections with high number of cells, because of a linear search.

A better approach would be to use `Tuple<sbyte,sbyte>` instead of an array:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte,sbyte>, Cell> CellList;
//....
Cell thisCell = CellList[Tuple.Create(thisX , thisY)];
```

Comment: Thanks for the input -- I didn't even know about the Tuple!

Answer (score 2):

> once the grid has been created the size will stay the same (all grids
>   will be the same size) and the object associated with each cell wont
>   change

Then the more efficient would be a multidimensional array:

```
// Creates array
Cell[,] array = new Cell[20, 50];

// Access to items (get item by X/Y indexes)
array[10, 12] = ...;
```

---

> Wondering how the Cell[,] compares to the Dictionary, Cell> approach

`Cell[,]` doesn't need to perform a `HashTable` lookup each time you want to access to an item, so it's more efficient. Let's write some benchmark to give some ideas (note it's probably not the best benchmark one could write, but at least it gives some ideas):

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int[,] array = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            array = ArrayInit();
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ArrayInit: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>, int> dic = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            dic = DictionaryInit();
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("DictionaryInit: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int res;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            res = ArrayLookup(array);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ArrayLookup: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            res = DictionaryLookup(dic);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("DictionaryLookup: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static int[,] ArrayInit()
    {
        int[,] array = new int[50, 50];
        for (sbyte x = 0; x < 50; x++)
        {
            for (sbyte y = 0; y < 50; y++)
            {
                array[x, y] = x * y;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static int ArrayLookup(int[,] array)
    {
        return array[12, 12];
    }

    private static int DictionaryLookup(Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>, int> dic)
    {
        return dic[new Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>(12, 12)];
    }

    private static Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>, int> DictionaryInit()
    {
        Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>, int> dic = new Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>, int>();
        for (sbyte x = 0; x < 50; x++)
        {
            for (sbyte y = 0; y < 50; y++)
            {
                Tuple<sbyte, sbyte> t = new Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>(x, y);
                dic[t] = x * y;
            }
        }

        return dic;
    }
```

Results:

> ArrayInit: 25
>
> DictionaryInit: 528
>
> ArrayLookup: 7
>
> DictionaryLookup: 326

Comment: +1. As long as the array isn't very big and mostly empty (i.e. a _sparse_ array), this seems to be the best way to go.

Comment: I like this for efficiency; but I am thinking that there would be some drawback (that were not specified in my questions) when it comes to finding cells with specific properties as an array of cells doesn't let me do a linq search correct?

Comment: Thanks for all the great info -- is there an easy (and efficient) way to do a linq like search on an array like this?   I need to be able to do something like: `CellList.First(cell => cell.cellType == CellType.red && cell.value >= 4);` -- If there is a way to do that I will use this as it's faster and mark it as the answer. - Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is much more efficient, since it uses a `HashTable` internally, while using a list will have to search though every item in the list every time you want to extract a cell.

However, I'd recommend using a `Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>` as a key instead of an array:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<sbyte, sbyte>, Cell> CellList;
Cell thisCell = CellList[Tuple.Create(thisX, thisY)];
```

Or possibly create your own key type:

```
struct Point 
{ 
    public sbyte X { get; private set; }
    public sbyte Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(sbyte x, sbyte y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.X << 8 | this.Y;
    }

    ...
}

Dictionary<Point, Cell> CellList
Cell thisCell = CellList[new Point(thisX, thisY)];
```